# replace all numbers and everything after them in JAVA but when there is a hyphen no to do anything

Tags: java

I have strings like 'Alian 12WE'
                      "ANI1451'
                        'ANI 14-ti'

so is there any way to replaceall the numbers **and everything after them**..but when there is hyphen (-) after the numbers not to relace anything 
so the outputshould look like   'Alian '
                                 'ANI'
                                   'ANI 14-ti'

Comment: did you even try something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String numberless = input.replaceAll("\\d+($|[^-].*)", "");
```